# Openwrt spi not work in PHP

Tags: php, lua, openwrt, spi

I have GL.Inet device running Openwrt.

I would like to connect AVR with SPI to GL.Inet as digital inputs and outputs.

For SPI I using spi_gpio_custom and verify function with logic analyser.

I make two testing script. One in Lua and second in PHP with same function. But script in PHP does not work properly. If i try read bytes in PHP i havent pulses on CLK GPIO.

### test script in PHP:   write is ok, but read not work

```
#!/usr/bin/php-cli
<?php 

$data_file = fopen("/dev/spidev1.0","r+");

fwrite($data_file,"some data");
$out_string = fread($data_file,5); 

fclose($data_file);

echo $out_string;

?>
```

[Img of logic analyser capture](http://postimg.org/image/7xku27bm9/)

### test script in Lua:   write and read is ok

```
#!/usr/bin/lua

local function main()

data_file = io.open("/dev/spidev1.0","r+")

data_file:write("some data")
out_string = data_file:read(5)

data_file:close()

io.write(out_string)

end

main()
```

[Img of logic analyser capture with correct read](http://postimg.org/image/3m77zow5l/)

How I can read SPI data from PHP?

Comment: `r+` opens the file for read/write, and puts the pointer at the start of the file, since you WRITE some text first, then READ, the file pointer will be at the END of whatever your wrote. If that new text is longer than whatever was in the file to start with, you'll be reading from the end-of-the-file, and get nothing.